# unreachable statement in laravel when executing a function

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, gmail

Am trying to execute a send mail function when a record is stored in the database but am getting unreachable statement

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $visit = Visit::create($request->all());
        return response()->json($visit);
        $this->sendEmail($request);

    }
```

This is the send email function

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request){
        $visit = Visit::create($request->all());
        $host_email = Db::table('users')
            ->where('name', '=', $visit->visitor_host)
            ->value('email');

        $to_name =  $request->input('visitor_name');
        $data = array('name'=> $to_name, "body" => "Test mail");


        Mail::send('mails.mail', $data, function($message) {
            $message->from('cytonnvisitor@gmail.com','cytonn');
            $message->to('mimikiduchu@gmail.com');
            $message->subject('Visitor coming notification');

        });
    }
```

Comment: when i do that no record is saved in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
>   the value of the function call.

Change your code to

```
$this->sendEmail($request);
return response()->json($visit);
```

to execute the mail send before your return.

Comment: when i do that no record is saved in the database

Comment: You probably shouldn't `$visit = Visit::create($request->all());` in your `sendEmail()` method, you've already done that in your `store()` method (why do it twice?). Pass `$visit` to your `sendEmail()` method

Comment: as the third parameter in sendmail()?

Comment: The _second_ parameter, yes, your `sendEmail()` only has _one_ parameter right now

Answer (score 0):

Enter return `response()->json($visit);` at the end of the store function.